# Linking to an anchor/id located in another page

Tags: hyperlink, anchor

I'm trying trying to link to specific sections of the page below using the ID anchor tags. You can see they work when you're on this page: http://lastergroup.com/epe/epe19-240/dev/education.html, but when you navigate to other pages of this site, and click on any of the links on that dropdown menu, none work. What am I doing wrong? I have my IDs and links in place:

```
<div id="solarenergy">

<a href="education.html#solarenergy">Solar Energy</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was happening. After some research I learned that I have to use the anchor right before the div section I want to link to:

```
<a name="div1"></a>

<a href="page.htm#div1">Link</a>
```